# Git merging does not delete files

Tags: git, git-merge

I added an extension in a branch 'A' and pushed it to origin 'A'

1. git branch A
2. git add files
3. git push Origin A

   Merged those files with Staging branch
4. git checkout Staging
5. git fetch origin
6. git merge origin/Staging
7. git merge origin/A
8. git push origin Staging

Later I decided that I am going to do a modman install of the same extension, so went back to the same branch 'A' deleted those files which I previously added and pushed to origin branch 'A'

Did the same procedure as mentioned above, but after step 7, git merge origin/A,
I am still able to see the deleted files in my directory.

When I did a

```
git log file
```

it only shows the commit where I added them, does not show a commit where I deleted.
But when I do a

```
git log --name-status
```

It shows the file is deleted, something like

```
- D file
```

What is my fault? Why is it not deleting the files in the branch wherever I am merging?

Comment: Have you tried replicating the problem with a local practice repository?

Comment: Not really probably i can try that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've originally added the files to branch A.

```
branch A
```

does create a branch called A, but you still remain on your original branch, where you added the files.

```
git checkout -b A
```

creates branch A and checks it out immediately.